# Enabled especifics btns in a form

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, ms-access

I want to have a command to enable determinant buttons in my form, all in one.

Today I need to inform with button this way:

```
public function EnabledMenu ()

Form_FrmMenu.btnAnalyze.Enabled = True
Form_FrmMenu.btnVacation.Enabled = True
Form_FrmMenu.btnTicket.Enabled = True
Form_FrmMenu.btnBackup104.Enabled = True

end function
```

what I want is like below, but ocorrs an error: Expected: identifier or bracketed expression

```
public function EnabledMenu()

Dim vBtns1 As Variant
    vBtns1 = Array(btnAnalyze, btnVacation, btnTicket, btnBackup104, btnParameterStr)

Dim vBtn1 As Variant

For Each vBtn1 In vBtns1
    Form_FrmMenu. & vbtn1 & .enebled = true
Next vbtn

end function
```

it's possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically do this with the names of the controls (string).

```
Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array("btnAnalyze", "btnVacation", "btnTicket", "btnBackup104", "btnParameterStr")

Dim btn As Variant

For Each btn In arr 
    Form_FrmMenu.Controls(btn).Enabled = true
Next vbtn
```